# Get length of cathetus/i from length of hypothenuse and ratio between catheti?

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate the length of the [cathetus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus) in a triangle if I know the length of the hypotenuse and the ratio between the two catheti?

For example:

The hypotenuse is $5$cm long, and the ratio between the catheti is $4:3$ - how long are the catheti or either cathetus?

Comment: Most people would use the word "leg" rather than "cathetus", which I'd never seen before.  Just letting you know, because it might help you in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Used Wikipedia to translate the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the ratio be 1:r and the hypotenuse be h. Then the sides are then x and rx for some x. By the [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) we get $x^2+r^2*x^2=h^2$. So $x=\sqrt{{h^2}/(1+r^2)}$. We can then calculate rx, the other side.

Answer (score 1):

You can call one cathetus 4*x*, the other 3*x*, and apply Pythagora's theorem: (4*x*)<sup>2</sup>+(3*x*)<sup>2</sup>=5<sup>2</sup>.

You will obtain 25*x*<sup>2</sup>=25, which yields *x*=1. So one cathetus is 4cm, and the other 3cm.

(Remember that 3,4,5 is a Pythagorean triple)

Comment: How can I calculate it if the ratio is not constant?

Comment: Pythagorean theorem..